# change customvalidator message dynamically in clientside

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I wanna change customvalidator message dynamically in clientside by  ClientValidationFunction. In java script I have :

```
function valnationalid(source, arguments) {     
    if (arguments.Value == ""){         
        source.errormessage = "custom message here";
        arguments.IsValid = false;
    } else if (arguments.Value == "Something else"){
        source.errormessage = "another custom message here";
        arguments.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

and in body:

```
<input runat="server" id="txtnationalid" maxLength="10" name="txtnationalid" class='person ltr glow-onfocus customerCode required number' dir="ltr" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="valnationalid1" runat="server" EnableClientScript="true" ClientValidationFunction="valnationalid"  ValidateEmptyText="True" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtnationalid"> </asp:CustomValidator>
```

But no messages shows in my page.

Comment: Does your JS execute at all.  Also what are you trying to do, your validator would always return false.

Comment: Yes. I test it by writhing alert(STH.) in "if-else" structure and it appeared in my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

Replace

```
source.errormessage = "custom message here";
```

With

```
source.innerHTML = "custom message here";
```

Comment: I did it Jack but it still doesn't work. I even remove IF-Else and just write this : 
    'function valnationalid(source, arguments) {    
   source.errormessage = "custom message here";
   arguments.IsValid = false;
   
 }'
but it doesn't work.

Comment: Jack, it's interesting when I add alert("hi") at the end of if or else parts it works and hi shown in the screen.

Comment: @Farhad, I have edited my answer, please try `source.innerHTML`. Also I have removed the changes I asked you make because you have implemented these in your question